# Is a running max less efficient than calling max on a whole iterable?

Tags: python, time-complexity, big-o

I was looking at a problem to find the majority element in a list and wanted to compare two slightly different solutions. As I understand it, the way the max function works for comparing two elements is the same as it does for more. From that I assume that the time complexity of explicitly calling max repeatedly in a loop should be the same as calling max on the entire iterable, O(N), but the latter was faster.

These are the two solutions I was comparing:

```
def majorityElement(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
        from collections import defaultdict
        counts = defaultdict(int)
        res, maxCount = 0, 0

        for n in nums:
            counts[n] += 1
            res = n if counts[n] > maxCount else res
            maxCount = max(counts[n], maxCount)
        
        return res
```

```
class Solution:
    def majorityElement(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
        from collections import defaultdict
        counts = defaultdict(int)

        for n in nums:
            counts[n] += 1
        
        return max(counts, key = counts.get)
```

Could the latter have been faster because the former calls max at every iteration of the loop, instead of over the key value pairs which would be fewer in number in case every element is not unique? So is it just the matter of this particular case where there's lots of non unique elements?

Comment: *"So is it just the matter of this particular case where there's lots of non unique elements?"* - Well what happened when you measured the times for input with only unique elements?

Comment: Also, what were your times, and how did you measure?

Comment: The test cases are hidden to me, but I ran them against two lists on my own `l1 = [2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6]` and `l2 = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]` in order of `f1(l1)`, `f2(l1)`, `f1(l2)`, `f2(l2)`. The results were puzzling to me: 1.058699854183942e-05, 6.119000317994505e-06, 6.0679994930978864e-06, 3.36800076183863e-06.

Comment: @OccasionApple Have you tried using longer lists? Notice that there is always some overhead when taking a measurements, so it is not often that you can trust isolated results that are in the microseconds.